# Bootstrap 3 - navbar with two buttons on top of eachother

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a project in HTML/CSS with Bootstrap and I was wondering if a responsive navigation bar as in the image is possible. (The toggle button for when the viewport is small is not included). I want a navigation bar consisting of a row split up in three areas: the first two consisting of regular buttons and the last one consisting of two buttons stacked on top of each other.

[image: The desired ordening of my navigation bar]

My code so far looks like this:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar_content">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-center"></i>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                TEST
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar_content" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="av navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">Routine surveu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Specific survey</a></li>
                <li><a href="#help">Help</a></li>
                <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
            </ul>                                 
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I have no idea, however, how to go on from here ... Some help from someone more experienced would be much appreciated ...

Thanks in advance and best regards,
Joshua

Comment: I mean at the most base level this would be achieved by putting the two anchor links (Help and Settings) in a single `<li></li>`.  After that it's just applying the necessary styles to reduce the font and icon size.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was so fixated on doing something with the grid system that I oversaw how simple it could be! This is exactly what I need. I wish you had posted this as an answer so I could upvote it!